# jQuery animate is moving the window scrollbar and bouncing after completion

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, scrollbar

I am revealing a hidden nav on click. It is a div that is in fixed position at the top of a bootstrap template.

I want the nav to slide down after clicking whilst also adjusting the top margin of the lower page content. All this is working but I have an unwanted bouncing effect and the scroll bar is also moving slightly down each time the nav reveals itself.

HTML:

```
          <!-- Member Site Sub Nav 2 -->
          <div class="col-xs-12 member-sub-nav-b" id="memberSubNavB">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="">DESIGNATIONS</a></li>
              <li><a href="">MEMBERSHIP PRICING SCHEDULE</a></li>
              <li><a href="">LOCUMS</a></li>
              <li><a href="">MEMBERSHIP TYPES</a></li>
              <li><a href="">MEMBER REWARDS</a></li>
              <li><a href="">ASSOCIATES & LIFE MEMBERS</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>  
        </div>
        <!-- Member Site Sub Nav 2 Ends -->  

        </div>

        <!-- Section Begins -->
        <section id="data" class="member-text row">

            <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
```

And the jQuery:

```
 function subNavB(){
  $('#mainLogo').click(function(){

      $('#memberSubNavB').slideDown(200, 'linear');
      $('.col-md-10').animate({'marginTop':'2.5em'}, 200, 'linear');

});
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity... clicking a logo is known for decades that you'll go to the Main page - why changing that so well established UI? Also be more specific while using your selectors, `'.col-md-10'` will animate every single `'.col-md-10'` in your Bootstrap document.

Comment: click logo is just for testing

Comment: yep understand col-md-10 also just to get the ball rolling

Comment: I'd need to create a whole bootstrap project and implement your code just to see an example and help you... I have not the time currently (You can do that instead!) - What I can tell you right my first thought is that the jumpiness is caused by incorrectly wrapped elements that have margins. The animation animates the element height, but misses to animate the margins > therefore the ugly snap!-jump.

Comment: its just a fixed hidden div that slides out under a fixed nav. 

http://www.bootply.com/EtaZW2bH0F